# There may be no DNS name server shards remaining for the name. Google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am new to GCP and trying to configure a zone for my static IP address on google cloud platform. However, I get this error whenever I try creating the zone yet I have only one VM in my project.

**The domain "mywebsitename." (or its child domains) may be reserved or registered already, prohibited by policy, or there may be no DNS name server shards remaining for the name. For more information see https://cloud.google.com/dns/quotas#nameserver_limits.**

Comment: You can only create DNS public zones and resource records for domains you **own/control** except if you are creating private zones. Also, you can only register valid names. **mywebsitename.** is not a valid name.

Comment: Thanks, John. I identified that the problem was with the name I used. It was not valid. I added the **.com** extension and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a limit, it's more likely the name is already in use by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a resource record with an invalid name. The name **mywebsitename.** (notice the period at the end) is an invalid name.

The period means something. It is the root name. In your case you are trying to create a gTLD (global top level domain) as **mywebsitename** + **root**.

The solution is to either create a relative name (remove the period) or create a fully qualified domain name (add .com).

Change the name to **mywebsite.com**